# Phrase-based translation at Google API PBMT

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to use phrase-based machine translation as provided by the Google API (PBMT).

Is it possible to provide Google with my own mappings of terms between languages, thus extending their phrase table?

Thank you! 
cheers
zabe

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: It's not possible.

The parameters you can specify in a Translation Request are only the ones listed in the [Translate Method reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate).

If you're interested, Google released [Cloud AutoML Translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/), which allows to train models using sentence pairs. Its model is not phrase-based though, so it may be not what you exactly want.

For phrase-based model specifically, the only (long-shot) alternative is to go to the [Google Translation Community](https://translate.google.com/community) to provide your own pairs / mappings and wait until Google enhances the Phrase-based model.